# Laravel ServerException in RequestException.php when receiving simple JSON request

Tags: php, json, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5 framework to communicate with the manufacturer, and I'm struggling in receiving the callback:

Here are the routes (set them both, just to test):

```
Route::post('/callback', 'PrintController@callback');
Route::get('/callback', 'PrintController@callback');
```

And the simple method in controller:

```
public function callback(Request $request)
{
    var_dump( $request );
    //Storage::put('request.txt', $request);
}
```

It works fine, if I open the site manually ( meaning, it dump the request and later create the request file ) , but when  call like like this:

```
/**
 * Test callback option
 */
public function testCallback()
{
    $callback_url = 'http://project.dev/callback';

    // Prepare response
    $response = array(
        'time' => -microtime(true),
    );

    $data = [
        "id" => 907,
        "current_state" => "Shipped",
        "merchant_sku" => "BST123",
        "ordered_on_date" => "2015-08-16T00:00:00+0200",
        "ship_by_date" => "2015-08-21T00:00:00+0200",
        "shipping_carrier" => "USPS",
        "shipping_tracking" => "9499907123456123456781",
    ];

    try {
        $result = Guzzle::post($callback_url, [
            'verify' => false,
            'headers' => [
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
            ],
            'json' => $data,
        ]);
        $body = json_decode($result->getBody(), true);

        // Fill response
        if ($body['success'] == true) {
            $response['success'] = true;
            $response['order_id'] = $body['work_order_id'];
        } else {
            $response['success'] = false;
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        // Set error
        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = $e->getMessage();
    }

    // Save execution time
    $response['time'] += microtime(true);
    $response['time'] = round(abs($response['time']), 4);

    return $response;
}
```

I get this error message:

```
ServerException in RequestException.php line 107:
Server error: `POST http://project.dev/callback` resulted in a `500 Internal Server Error` response:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="robots" content="noindex,nofollow" />
<style>
(truncated...)
```

*Edit:* The only errorlike message I get in `php_error.log` is:

```
[09-May-2016 12:24:20 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Automatically populating $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated and will be removed in a future version. To avoid this warning set 'always_populate_raw_post_data' to '-1' in php.ini and use the php://input stream instead. in Unknown on line 0
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong and/or how to debug and fix this?

By the way: The communication happens between two laravel frameworks in the save machine, meaning, it's `site.dev` sending request to `project.dev`.

*EDIT:* Found this in laravel error log when receiveing POST. It works find with GET.

```
[2016-05-09 15:21:25] local.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in D:\project.dev\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken.php:67
```

Why does Laravel even care about this, since I'm sending request with `'verify' => false` ?

Comment: can you reproduce the error using postman for example? Set env to local and debug to true and laravel will most probably tell you whats wrong.

Comment: @FrankProvost sorry for late response. I already have debug on and I can't see anything that leads to the right error, *but* it works fine, when I send a get request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. I moved the routes *outside* middleware, so it doesn't require the token validation:

```
Route::post('/callback', 'PrintController@callback');
Route::get('/callback', 'PrintController@callback');

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    ...
}
```

Just in case someone else has this same problem: middleware is **not** required here, since the manufacturer doesn't use the same session and can't provide the token required.